# cannot find symbol method charAt(int) with a showInputDialog with a custom icon

Tags: java, joptionpane

Well i have an error and i don't know why. I create a custom icon for my JOptionPane.showInputDialog and i cannot make it equals something for exemple:

```
final ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon("test.png");
lettrependu = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, sortie,"Dat Title",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon2, null, "").charAt(0);
```

gave me this error: cannot find symbol method charAt(int)...
it don't work too with the String, int, etc..

I canno't place any value with my custom icon if i remove it, it works, but i want it.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of [Cannot find symbol method charAt(int) with showInputDialog with a custom icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792078/cannot-find-symbol-method-charatint-with-showinputdialog-with-a-custom-icon)